# Can't find my question by tags

Tags: support, tags, search

I created a question about 3 hours ago - [Touch draw in Quatz 2D/Core Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951963/touch-draw-in-quatz-2d-core-graphics)

I can read it from my profile but if I click on any of its tags - I can't find this question in the list. I don't really know is it a bug or what...
Could you please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the listings for all 5 tags. I sort by Newest, so I just checked for "asked 3 hours ago". What are your sort options?

Another cause can be if you are ignoring one of the 5 tags. Is anything in your "Ignored" tags one of the tags on the question, or would include one such tag as a wildcard result? If this is true and you have enabled the option to hide all "Ignored" tags, then you would not be able to see the question on the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I think it was by default set to "Hot"(not sure, because I switched to "Featured" before you answered). I never change it before.
Thanks for the answer and sorry for such stupid question.